# SVG is completely black when converting to PDF or opening with Inkscape

Tags: svg, colors, inkscape

I created a simple image in SVG. When i open it in Inkscape every information about the color is lost. Why is that?

This is part of my code:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="300px" height="300px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <!-- light-blue-green: #00b3aaff -->
  <!-- light-blue-green: rgba(0, 179, 170, 1) -->
  <!-- dark-blue-green: #018273ff -->

  <!-- light-gray: #efeae0ff -->
  <!-- dark-gray: #aa9991ff -->
  
  <!-- light-red: #ff786eff -->
  <!-- dark-red: #be5652ff -->

  <!-- background -->
  <path d="M30,150 a50, 50 0, 0, 1 240, 0" style="fill:rgba(0, 179, 170, 1)" />
  <path d="M30,150 a50, 50 0, 0, 0 240, 0" fill="#018273ff" />
  <path d="M35,150 a50, 50 0, 0, 0 230, 0" fill="#00b3aaff" />
  <path d="M35,150 a50, 50 0, 0, 1 230, 0" fill="#018273ff" />
  
  <!-- ball -->
  <circle cx="50%" cy="10%" r="15" fill="#aa9991ff" />
  <path d="M140,19 a10,10, 45, 0, 1, 21,21 a10,8, 45, 0, 1, -21,-21 Z" fill="#efeae0ff"/>
</svg>
```

This is what Inkscape shows me: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qf5JM.jpg)

I tried to convert my code using `style` but it is still black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying your fill colors, leave out the alpha (opacity) channel. In SVG 1.1, [colors are only RGB](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/types.html#DataTypeColor), not RGBA, and while browsers usually do accept RGBA as an extension, [Inkscape doesn't yet](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/1195).

Remove the last two hex digits in the hex colors:

```
fill="#018273ff"
```

```
fill="#018273"
```

and remove the last argument to `rgba` as well as the `a`:

```
style="fill:rgba(0, 179, 170, 1)"
```

```
style="fill:rgb(0, 179, 170)"
```

If you do want transparency (opacity, alpha), you can use the `opacity`, `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity` attributes instead, which are in SVG 1.1.